# selectBooleanCheckbox in icefaces

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

```
<ice:column style="width: 30px;">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox
                            value="#{createToolsOrderInwardsBean.test}" 
                            partialSubmit="true"
                            valueChangeListener="#{createToolsOrderInwardsBean.selectInwardQuantityChk}"
                            id="slc-tlmanage-selectallee"></ice:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{currentRow.chkInwardQuantity}"
                        immediate="true" partialSubmit="true" style="margin-left: 10px;"
                        id="slc-tlmanage-enableinput"></ice:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </ice:column>
```

I have this code whtin ocefaces datatable.When i select first one than all other checkbox whin that column of datatable will be selected.

below i described a valuchage method

```
 public void selectInwardQuantityChk(ValueChangeEvent evt){
        if(evt != null){
            Boolean value =(Boolean)evt.getNewValue();
            if(test)
                for(int i=0;i<this.toolsOrderVO.getToolsOrderItemVOList().size();i++){
                    this.toolsOrderVO.getToolsOrderItemVOList().get(i).setChkInwardQuantity(value);
                    System.out.println("int the for loop for changing value ============>"+this.toolsOrderVO.getToolsOrderItemVOList().get(i).getChkInwardQuantity());
                }

        }
    }
```

method called and even checkbox value can't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were considerable typos in your question, So my understanding of your problem could be patchy. If I understand your problem correctly, then it can be solved easily.

Add this line to your event handler.(At the start of the method)

```
if (!evt.getPhaseId().equals(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION)) {
            evt.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
            evt.queue();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Yes its work perfect.If its possible, can you explain why it require ?

Comment: This has to do with request lifecycle.Listeners are called before updating the model values in the lifecycle, so any changes you make in that phase are overwritten by the actual values in the page.Hence we are changing the phase to Invoke Application, so that the changes made are not overwritten.